# No applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "MXFeedForwardModel"

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service, mxnet

I have created a Neural network model using mxnet package in R studio. I tested the model on local and it works as expected. I have deployed the same model as a webservice in AzureML using `publishwebservice()` function from R.

When I try to predict the test data with the webservice using `consume()` function:

```
pred_cnn <- consume(endpoint_cnn, testdf)
```

it always throws following error:

> Error: AzureML returns error code: HTTP status code : 400 AzureML
>   error code  : LibraryExecutionError
>
> Module execution encountered an internal library error.
>   The following
>   error occurred during evaluation of R script: R_tryEval: return error: 
>   Error in UseMethod("predict") :
>      no applicable method for 'predict'
>   applied to an object of class "MXFeedForwardModel"

Comment: The first point of failure is `HTTP status code: 400` which implies a "bad request",  output of  `traceback()` could shed more light

Comment: `Cough` - gentle reminder that we prefer not to see [mentions of urgency here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). Remember that it's volunteers that are reading your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Azure Machine Learning Service platform is running services in windows containers that might not be compatible with the compiled version of MXNet you are uploading with your service.

I would recommend a different operationalization platform, for example if you prefer to remain in the Microsoft ecosystem have a look at [Microsoft R Server Operationalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/what-is-operationalization).